# use recursive function to draw multicolored dots on canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have created a small application to create dots on an HTML canvas element. Here I have written code to draw multicolored dots in canvas.

I have created one button to change the color of the dots, And another button to sort the dots in a single line.

All are working perfectly.

```js
"use strict";

//Canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),

//Buttons
    randColBtn = document.getElementById('randColBtn'),
    randPosBtn = document.getElementById('randPosBtn'),
    sortDotsBtn = document.getElementById('sortDotsBtn'),

//Globals
    dots = [],
    color = '#AAAAAA';

//Constants
const DOT_RADIUS = 20;


//Dot constructor
var Dot = function(x, y, c) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.color = c;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x-DOT_RADIUS/2, this.y-DOT_RADIUS/2, DOT_RADIUS, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

//Checks if the mouse has clicked within the boundaries of an existing dot
var isOverlap = function(d) {
  for (var i = dots.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let normalizedX = d.x - dots[i].x,
        normalizedY = d.y - dots[i].y;
    if (-DOT_RADIUS < normalizedX && normalizedX < DOT_RADIUS && -DOT_RADIUS < normalizedY && normalizedY < DOT_RADIUS) {
      dots.splice(i,1);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


//Event listeners
canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {  
  var dot = new Dot(e.clientX,e.clientY,color);
  if (!isOverlap(dot)) {
    dot.draw();
    dots.push(dot);
  } else {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].draw();
    }
  }
});

randColBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  color = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + ")";
});

randPosBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].x = Math.random()*canvas.width;
    dots[i].y = Math.random()*canvas.height;
    dots[i].draw();
  }
});

sortDotsBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].x = 2*DOT_RADIUS*i%canvas.width + 3/2*DOT_RADIUS;
    dots[i].y = Math.floor(2*DOT_RADIUS * i/canvas.width) * 2*DOT_RADIUS + 3/2*DOT_RADIUS;
    dots[i].draw();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DOT CLICKER</title>

  <style>
    #canvas {
      border: thin solid black;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=400></canvas>
  <div>
    <button id="randColBtn" type="button">Randomize Colour</button>
    <button id="randPosBtn" type="button">Randomize Position</button>
    <button id="sortDotsBtn" type="button">Sort Dots</button>
  </div>

  <script src="dots.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now I want to create a recursive function to draw the dots 10 times with a different color.
So what should I have to change in this code?

Comment: Do you want draw 10 dots on click?

Comment: @Firanolfind yes i want 10 dots on a click using recursive function.

Comment: Add the `dots.js` so that we can run the code ourselves. On a side note why does the dot adding you want to implement have to be recursive ? You are already adding dots in `dots.push(dot);`

Comment: Also you should organize your code a little better. You are drawing the dots in several functions, so it would be better to create a drawing function and call it wherever it is necessary.

Comment: @Isac But i have to use recursive function and i am begginer that why i am learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, Check this out:
I reorganized your code and created a new function to generate 10 random dots with random colors.

```js
//Canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),

//Buttons
    randColBtn = document.getElementById('randColBtn'),
    randPosBtn = document.getElementById('randPosBtn'),
    sortDotsBtn = document.getElementById('sortDotsBtn'),

//Globals
    dots = [],
    color = '#AAAAAA';

//Constants
const DOT_RADIUS = 20;


//Dot constructor
var Dot = function(x, y, c) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.color = c;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x-DOT_RADIUS/2, this.y-DOT_RADIUS/2, DOT_RADIUS, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

//Checks if the mouse has clicked within the boundaries of an existing dot
var isOverlap = function(d) {
  for (var i = dots.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let normalizedX = d.x - dots[i].x,
        normalizedY = d.y - dots[i].y;
    if (-DOT_RADIUS < normalizedX && normalizedX < DOT_RADIUS && -DOT_RADIUS < normalizedY && normalizedY < DOT_RADIUS) {
      dots.splice(i,1);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


//Event listeners
function canvasClick(e) {
    var dot = new Dot(e.clientX,e.clientY,color);
    if (!isOverlap(dot)) {
        dot.draw();
        dots.push(dot);
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].draw();
        }
    }
}
canvas.addEventListener("click", canvasClick,event);

function rndColor() {
    color = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + ")";
}
randColBtn.addEventListener("click", rndColor);

function rndPosition() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].x = Math.random()*canvas.width;
        dots[i].y = Math.random()*canvas.height;
        dots[i].draw();
    }
}
randPosBtn.addEventListener("click", rndPosition);

function sortDots() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].x = 2*DOT_RADIUS*i%canvas.width + 3/2*DOT_RADIUS;
        dots[i].y = Math.floor(2*DOT_RADIUS * i/canvas.width) * 2*DOT_RADIUS + 3/2*DOT_RADIUS;
        dots[i].draw();
    }
}
sortDotsBtn.addEventListener("click", sortDots);
function randDots(i) {
debugger;
    rndColor();
    canvasClick(0,0);
    if (i==0){
        rndPosition();
        return;
    }
    randDots(--i);
}
randDotsBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    randDots(10);
});
```

```css
 #canvas {
      border: thin solid black;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=400></canvas>
  <div>
    <button id="randColBtn" type="button">Randomize Colour</button>
    <button id="randPosBtn" type="button">Randomize Position</button>
    <button id="sortDotsBtn" type="button">Sort Dots</button>
    <button id="randDotsBtn" type="button">Rand Dots</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement your idea [HERE in JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xozelayuye/1/edit?js,output). You can adjust quantity of your dots and bouncing value

```
// dots qty
var limit = 10;
// random bouncing value
var bouncing = [-100, 100];
var rand = (min, max) => ~~(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
// randomize you color 
var randColor = ()=> "rgb(" + ~~(Math.random()*256) + "," + ~~(Math.random()*256) + "," + ~~(Math.random()*256) + ")";

// generate list of random dots
var newDots = [...Array(limit||0)]
    .map((v,i) => new Dot(
         e.clientX + rand.apply(null, bouncing),
         e.clientY + rand.apply(null, bouncing),
         randColor() 
    ))
// draw new dots
newDots.forEach(dot=>dot.draw());
//extend global dots
dots = [...dots, ...newDots];
```

Comment: Here I want 10 dots that are in different color and use recursive function for it

Comment: I updated, now colors are random. Why recursive function?